# Where is the config.xml from when clickhouse container starts up?

Tags: dockerfile, containers, clickhouse

questions about the dockerfile of clickhouse server

I wonder where the /etc/clickhouse/config.xml is from when building the image

I read the dockerfile and entrypoint.sh from master branch of clickhouse [dockerfile](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker/server/Dockerfile.ubuntu),
[entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker/server/entrypoint.sh)

If I don't set build-arg *deb_location_url* and *single_binary_location_url* when building the image, so it goes to this code block.

> else 
> mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
> apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 8919F6BD2B48D754 
> echo ${REPOSITORY} > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list 
> echo "installing from repository: ${REPOSITORY}" 
> apt-get update 
> apt-get --yes -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold" upgrade 
> for package in ${PACKAGES}; do 
> packages="${packages} ${package}=${VERSION}" 
> done 
> apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated --yes --no-install-recommends ${packages} || exit 1 
> fi \

And after that I don't find where the config.xml is from because in entrypoint.sh, it uses this file to get DATA_DIR and something else. And actually I build this image and docker run it, the container exits and logs like not found the file config.xml.

I'm confused about it, I am new to docker, I wonder if I missed some command that makes config.xml generated at container startup.  Can someone tells me what's wrong with me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Denny said, it is there.  During the `docker build` you should see the ClickHouse deb repository get added and then clickhouse-server and client debs get installed.  The default config is installed then.  There is also a `docker-related.xml` that gets copied from the local disk during the build and placed in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/

I moved the Dockerfile.ubuntu out of the docker dir so I could watch what happens with no assumptions;  here is my history:

```
mkdir /tmp/container
cp Dockerfile.ubuntu /tmp/container/Dockerfile
cd /tmp/container
docker build --network=host -t dockertest .
cp /work/Docs/ClickHouse/docker/server/entrypoint.sh .
cp /work/Docs/ClickHouse/docker/server/docker_related_config.xml .
docker build --network=host -t dockertest .

docker run -it --network host dockertest bash
# Since you are new to Docker, adding `bash` at the
# end of the command gives a bash shell in the container.
# I use this to look around.

# the default config.xml is in /etc/clickhouse-server/
# and the docker-related.xml is in 
# /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/

docker run -it --network host dockertest
clickhouse client
```

For more Docker examples, see https://github.com/ClickHouse/examples/tree/main/docker-compose-recipes

Comment: ok, so the default config is installed when adding the deb repository, I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's in `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`

You don't need to change `config.xml` https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-server-config-files/

You can pass settings like this:

```
cat  ~/Documents/docker/click/config.d/disable_open_network.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<clickhouse>
  <http_port remove="1"/>
</clickhouse>

docker run -d --name test  -v ~/Documents/docker/click/config.d:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 -p 9000:9000  -p 8123:8123 clickhouse/clickhouse-server
```